# Website not working on FireFox but works on Safari and Chrome

Tags: php, html

I have made a simple website to allow the user to sell an item and then view a list of the items for sale. It works perfectly on Safari and in Chrome but it doesn't work on FireFox. I only came across this during testing. I will post my code for the input form and the processing php and then the error I get in Firefox.

FORM:

```
<?php
// Define variables and set to empty values
$titleErr = $descriptionErr = $priceErr = $quantityErr = $durationErr = $locationErr = "";
$title = $description = $price = $quantity = $duration = $location = "";
$valid = FALSE;

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$valid = TRUE;

if (empty($_POST["title"])) {
    $titleErr = "Title is required";
    $valid = FALSE;
} 
else {
    $title = test_input($_POST["title"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["description"])) {
    $descriptionErr = "A description is required";
    $valid = FALSE;
} 
else {
    $description = test_input($_POST["description"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $description)) {
        $descriptionErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
}

if (empty($_POST["price"])) {
    $priceErr = "A price is required";
    $valid = FALSE;
} 
else {
    $price = test_input($_POST["price"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["quantity"])) {
    $quantityErr = "A quantity is required";
    $valid = FALSE;
} 
else {
    $quantity = test_input($_POST["quantity"]);
}


if (empty($_POST["duration"])) {
    $durationErr = "Duration is required";
    $valid = FALSE;
} 
else {
    $duration = test_input($_POST["duration"]);
}


if (empty($_POST["location"])) {
    $locationErr = "A location is required";
    $valid = FALSE;
} 
else {
    $location = test_input($_POST["location"]);
}


// If valid then redirect
if($valid){
    header('Location: sell_your_item.php');
    exit();
}
}

// Function to remove spaces, strip slashes and allow special characters to be used in form
function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Sell Your Item</title>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>


<div>
<h2>Sell your item</h2><br>
<section>
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap" data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="form.php">Sell an item</a></li>
        <li><a href="list_items.php">Items for sale</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</section><br><br>
<p><span class="error">* required.</span></p>
<form method="post" onsubmit='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>' enctype="multipart/form-data">
Title: &nbsp;
<input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $title;?>">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $titleErr;?></span>
    <br><br>
Description: &nbsp;
<textarea class="textarea" name="description" rows="2" cols="50" value="<?php echo $description;?>">
</textarea>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $descriptionErr;?></span>
    <br><br>
Choose A Picture: &nbsp;
<input type="file" name="picture" value="<?php echo $picture;?>">
    <br><br>
Category: &nbsp;
<select name="category">
    <option 
    value="Collectables" <?php if(isset($_POST['category']) && $_POST['category'] == 'Collectables') echo "selected"; ?>    
    name="Collectables">Collectables</option>
    <option 
    value="Electronics" <?php if(isset($_POST['category']) && $_POST['category'] == 'Electronics') echo "selected"; ?>
    name="Electronics">Electronics</option>
    <option 
    value="Vehicles" <?php if(isset($_POST['category']) && $_POST['category'] == 'Vehicles') echo "selected"; ?>
    name="Vehicles">Vehicles</option>
    <option 
    value="Children" <?php if(isset($_POST['category']) && $_POST['category'] == 'Children') echo "selected"; ?>
    name="Children">Children</option>
    <option 
    value="Clothing" <?php if(isset($_POST['category']) && $_POST['category'] == 'Clothing') echo "selected"; ?>
    name="Clothing">Clothing</option>
    <option 
    value="Fitness" <?php if(isset($_POST['category']) && $_POST['category'] == 'Fitness') echo "selected"; ?>
    name="Fitness">Fitness</option>
    <option 
    value="Homegarden" <?php if(isset($_POST['category']) && $_POST['category'] == 'Homegarden') echo "selected"; ?>
    name="Homegarden">Home &amp; Garden</option>
</select>
    <br><br>
Starting Price: &nbsp;
<input type="number" name="price" min="0.01" step="0.01" value="<?php echo $price;?>">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $priceErr;?></span>
    <br><br>
Quantity: &nbsp;
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="99" value="<?php echo $quantity;?>">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $quantityErr;?></span>
    <br><br>
Duration (days): &nbsp;
<input type="number" name="duration" min="1" max="10" value="<?php echo $duration;?>">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $durationErr;?></span>
    <br><br>
Location: &nbsp;
<input type="text" name="location" value="<?php echo $location;?>">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $locationErr;?></span>
    <br><br>
Auction Type: &nbsp;
<select name="auction_type">
    <option value="Fixed_price" <?php if(isset($_POST['auction_type']) && $_POST['auction_type'] == 'Fixedprice') echo "selected"; ?>
    name="fixedprice">Fixed Price Sale</option>
    <option value="Auction" <?php if(isset($_POST['auction_type']) && $_POST['auction_type'] == 'Auction') echo "selected"; ?>
    name="auction">Auction</option>
</select>
    <br><br>
Payment Method: &nbsp;
<select name="paymentType">
    <option value="PayPal" <?php if(isset($_POST['paymentType']) && $_POST['paymentType'] == 'PayPal') echo "selected"; ?>
    name="PayPal">PayPal</option>
    <option value="Creditcard" <?php if(isset($_POST['paymentType']) && $_POST['paymentType'] == 'Creditcard') echo "selected"; ?>
    name="Creditcard">Credit Card</option>
    <option value="Bank" <?php if(isset($_POST['paymentType']) && $_POST['paymentType'] == 'Bank') echo "selected"; ?>
    name="bank">Bank Deposit</option>
</select>
    <br><br>
Postage Details: &nbsp;
<select name="postage">
    <option value="Pickup" <?php if(isset($_POST['postage']) && $_POST['postage'] == 'Pickup') echo "selected"; ?>
    name="pickup">Pick Up only</option>
    <option value="Post" <?php if(isset($_POST['postage']) && $_POST['postage'] == 'Post') echo "selected"; ?>
    name="post">Postage available at buyer's expense</option>
</select>
    <br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

SELL_YOUR_ITEM.PHP:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Sell Your Item</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

// Maximum file size for the html upload form
$max_file_size = 50 * 1024 * 1024; // size in bytes

// The directory that will recieve the uploaded file
$dir = 'uploads/';

// Determine connection variables
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "ictdbs504";

// Create Connection 
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check Connection 
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// Escape user inputs for security
$sellingFormat = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['auction_type']);
$category = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['category']);
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['title']);
$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['description']);
$startPrice = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['price']);
$duration = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['duration']);
$quantity = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['quantity']);
$location = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['location']);
$paymentType = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['paymentType']);
$postageDetails = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['postage']);


//variables for images
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["picture"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);


$success = false;



// Check if form submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (strlen($title)>0 && strlen($description)>0) {
            $newFilePath = $dir . "/" . $title . "." . $extension;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $newFilePath);


            // Query database and insert data into item table
            $itemQry = 'INSERT INTO items (title, picture, startPrice, category, description, quantity, location, sellingFormat, duration, paymentType, postageDetails)
                        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
            $statement = $conn->prepare($itemQry);
            $statement->bind_param('sssssssssss', $title, $newFilePath, $startPrice, $category, $description, $quantity, $location, $sellingFormat, $duration, $paymentType, $postageDetails);
            $statement->execute();

            $success=true;

    }}          
            // If successful, redirect to this page
        if($success == true){
            header('Location: list_items.php');
            die(); }



?>
</body>
</html>
```

THE ERROR I RECEIVE:

Notice: Undefined index: auction_type in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ICTDBS504/sell_your_item.php on line 32

Notice: Undefined index: category in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ICTDBS504/sell_your_item.php on line 33

Notice: Undefined index: title in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ICTDBS504/sell_your_item.php on line 34

Notice: Undefined index: description in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ICTDBS504/sell_your_item.php on line 35

Notice: Undefined index: price in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ICTDBS504/sell_your_item.php on line 36

Notice: Undefined index: duration in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ICTDBS504/sell_your_item.php on line 37

Notice: Undefined index: quantity in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ICTDBS504/sell_your_item.php on line 38

Notice: Undefined index: location in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ICTDBS504/sell_your_item.php on line 39

Notice: Undefined index: paymentType in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ICTDBS504/sell_your_item.php on line 40

Notice: Undefined index: postage in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ICTDBS504/sell_your_item.php on line 41

Notice: Undefined index: picture in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ICTDBS504/sell_your_item.php on line 46

Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: This will be the same result in any browser. When you send the form to itself, the data is in the post array. When you then redirect to another page, it's gone. Also that test-input function is mostly useless and shouldn't be used like that

Answer (score 0):

You can post data directly to the sell_your_item.php rather then posting it to the same page and perform all the checking and save the data that way it will work.Currently you are only redirecting to a page but data is not passed to the page.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try.